# How to count document without query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Example I have collection users like this

```
[
   {
       name : 'John',
       age : 21,
   },
   {
       name : 'Ethan',
       age : 23,
   },
   {
       name : 'Jack',
       age : 21,
   },
]
```

I want to count how many type of age (result should be 2 because age have 21 and 23)
And how many of each type something like db.collection.anyFunctionForCount("help me field age please")
result i expect is

```
{"21" : 1 , "23" : 2}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use aggregation-framework in MongoDB default driver, or mongoose. That code should help you:

[MongoPlayground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6iH1BrzCkER)

```js
Model.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$age",
      "field1": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Can I ask one more thing?
When i use aggregation like bellow, final result which field "user" is an array, how can i make it return user as an object? 
Aggregation here : https://mongoplayground.net/p/r9NvbCPYr4a

Comment: @luongvy you can't. The aggregation framework always returns the result as [array]. Even if the result is single object. So the only way is using js modern syntax, like this:

`const [ result ] = await Model.aggregate([aggregation]);`

Comment: Thank you. I mean when I "populate" by lookup, return field is an array, but I found the way to convert it to object by project!